# Can you apply GARCH to ARIMAX models?

Tags: time-series, garch, regression

Is it possible to apply the idea of GARCH to time series models that include exogenous variables?

For example, say I estimate a cash flow forecast model. Does it make sense to model the residuals by use of a GARCH model? Or formulated alternatively: Does it make sense to try to forecast volatility in cash flow forecast errors by usage of a GARCH model?

Comment: Technically, this is possible. GARCH is a model of your residuals, ARIMA(X) is a model of your levels. Estimation / Calibration can become tedious, though.

Comment: Are there any lecture slides/papers you could point me to? Or programming packages?

Comment: I shenflow, I would suggest stats quantexchange for this, e.g. here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254101/forecasting-time-series-using-arma-garch-in-r

Comment: Agreed with @Kermittfrog regarding the technicalities of this estimation. However, if you could elaborate more on the cash flow modelling it would fit here better I think. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve though.

Comment: I am interested in forecasting the risk, defined as the volatility, in cash flows, as opposed to forecasting the conditional mean @Bob Jansen.

Comment: What kind of model are you using for forecasting? Is the model the source of the volatitiy of the cash flows? Do you have a reason to suspect autocorrelation in the volatility of the cash flows?

Comment: @Bob Jansen I am using a time series model with exogenous variables. I am not sure what you mean by your second sentence. I am trying to forecast volatility. I want to do that in a similar fashion as the mean is being forecasted, i.e. use historical data as an input to predict something in the future. And yes, I have reason to suspect autocorrelation in the volatility of the cash flows.

Comment: @Bob Jansen, for example. I have seen in one paper (A+), that the authors predict quantiles via quantile regression to derive dispersion measures in an earnings forecast setting. They subsequently employ these dispersion measures as "measures of earnings risk" and show how they correlate with things that are expected to correlate with risk. I want to do something similar, but by exploiting the residuals of a regression model as opposed to predicted quantiles.

Comment: @shenflow, your problem is pretty standard. See e.g. `rugarch` package in R, it has the capability and a nice vignette to illustrate things. See also `lgarch` and `gets` packages in R. The latter even does automated model selection for both the conditional mean and the conditional variance equations!